# Drupal: Changing the link of menu children to anchors

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

My goal is to modify the output of a menu so that the submenu links are anchors of the parent item:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="page1">Page 1</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a href="page1#section">Section</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Because the Drupal GUI doesn't allow anchors in menu items, I need to modify the `theme_link()` function to change all children:

```
function MYTHEME_menu_link__menu_block__main_menu(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {

    foreach($element['#below'] as $child) {
      $child['#href'] = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower(render($child['#title'])));
    }

    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";

}
```

But there are two problems, which are a result of my lack of experience with Drupal functions:

1. The changed `href` is not being passed to the rendered HTMl.
2. I receive this error for line 8: `Warning: Cannot use a scalar value
   as an array`.

What do I need to correct this error, and how can I pass the new `href` to the menu-children's output link?

EDIT: I should add that I’m using Entity Reference to pull nodes into one super page, and there are three super pages on the site. So using a single-page solution will not work for me.

Comment: Drupal in itself is not PHP, but it may run on PHP.

Comment: @eyeLoveFiddle, you're right. I'm aware that Drupal is not PHP, but it does feature specific functions, like the one I mentioned above.

Comment: then you could do this to the HTML for a dropdown menu: http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/vWDvy/

Comment: @eyeLoveFiddle, that doesn't answer my question. The menu is originally created in the Drupal interface, but I need to intercept and modify the rendered HTML before it's printed.

Comment: Then don't ask for PHP help.  I'm a PHP developer, and do it that way, not a drupal developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I decided to use a non-PHP solution for now. I’m using JavaScript to change the submenu-children's `href`s on page load, which is not necessarily the best solution, but the most feasible right now. It seems like Drupal’s menu functions are better served for modifying the markup and attributes of the menu items, rather than the menu's link attributes. If I return to this issue and come up with a PHP solution, I’ll post it here.

Even though this doesn’t answer my original questions, I’m marking it as the accepted answer because it provides the end result I trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get idea from Single Page Site module

httops://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site
It allows you to automatically create a single page from a menu. The module will render all the content from the links, that are configured in the menu, on one page. It will then override the menu links so that they refer to an anchor instead of a new page.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try, but it doesn't seem to play nicely with Entity Reference, which I should've mentioned using above. It also doesn't seem to work for multiple pages that need anchors.